# spark streaming hbase error

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I want to insert streaming data into `hbase`;
this is my code :

```
val tableName = "streamingz"
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.addResource(new Path("file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/etc/hbase/conf.dist/hbase-site.xml"))
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
if (!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
    tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("z1".getBytes()))
    tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("z2".getBytes()))
    admin.createTable(tableDesc)
} else {
    print("Table already exists!!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
}
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val topicSet = Set("fluxAstellia")
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" - > "10.32.201.90:9092")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)
val lines = stream.map(_._2).map(_.split(" ", -1)).foreachRDD(rdd => {
    if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
        val myTable = new HTable(conf, tableName)
        rdd.map(rec => {
            var put = new Put(rec._1.getBytes)
            put.add("z1".getBytes(), "name".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(rec._2))
            myTable.put(put)
        }).saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf)
        myTable.flushCommits()
    } else {
        println("rdd is empty")
    }

})


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

}
}
```

I got this error:

```
:66: error: value _1 is not a member of Array[String]
       var put = new Put(rec._1.getBytes)
```

I'm beginner so how I can't fix this error, and I have a question:

where exactly create the table; outside the streaming process or inside ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You error is basically on line `var put = new Put(rec._1.getBytes)`
You can call _n only on a Map(_1 for key and _2 for value) or a Tuple.
`rec` is a String Array you got by splitting the string in the stream by space characters. If you were after first element, you'd write it as `var put = new Put(rec(0).getBytes)`. Likewise in the next line you'd write it as `put.add("z1".getBytes(), "name".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(rec(1)))`

Comment: what about creating the hbase table. where should i create it?

Comment: i got this new error brother `ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1492790490000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Comment: It should tell you what class is not serializable in the stack trace. Whatever is in your map() closure should be serializable. My guess is HTable is not serializable. You can either make it serializable by replacing the line with `val myTable = new HTable(conf, tableName) with java.io.Serializable` or perhaps mark it as `@transient lazy` so each executor creates its own instance if thats what you want to do.

Comment: thank you for your answer brother but i still have the same problem